# Is it appropriate to remove low-quality/downvoted answer?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

Long time ago, when I'm still new to this site. I posted 4-5 answer to different question, and all of them got downvote. I recently figured out that they're low quality answer.

So is it okay to remove them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove them if, and *only if* they can not be improved. Deleting answers potentially deprives people of a solution. We (obviously) don't want to do that.

If a post can, at all, be salvaged and brought up to quality standards, this should be done instead. However, if there's absolutely no way to recover the answer, then a delete is most likely the best way to go.

This is even supported by official Stack Exchange policy. [Post bans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/259230) take into effect deleted posts (at a higher weight than non-deleted posts) into deciding whether you should or should not be allowed to post.